# Proof that a given relation is an equivalence relation

Tags: equivalence-relations

Can someone can tell me if my proof of the next propostion is correct?

**Define the following relation:**
$$a\sim b \iff a-b=km, m\in \mathbb{Z}$$
**Show $\sim$ is an equivalence relation**

And so here's my attempt on showing it

*Proof.*

Let $a, b, c \in \sim$

i)Reflexivity of $\sim$:
$$a\sim a \iff a-a = km \iff 0=km \iff k = 0 \in \mathbb{Z} \vee m=0 \in \mathbb{Z}$$
ii)Simmetry of $\sim$:
$$a\sim b \iff a-b = km \iff b-a = (-k)m\iff a\sim b$$
iii)Transitivity of $\sim$:
$$a\sim b \wedge b\sim c \iff a-b=km \wedge b-c=qm \iff a-b+b-c = km - qm $$
$$\iff a-c = km-qm \iff a-c = (k-q)m, (k-q)\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: yah- this is correct.

Comment: Please do not make your titles large. It takes up too much room on the main page.

Comment: The proof looks good to me! As for titles, note that (for my browser, at least) the content of the first few sentences of your post is already visible on the main page, and so I feel the title should be a very short summary, rather than a full restatement, of the problem.

Comment: I would just be careful using $\Longleftrightarrow$ when only $\Longrightarrow$ is true. But your proof is essentially correct.

Comment: @ZachL. Sorry about of the title stuff :/ and in which one only is true $\rightarrow$ on proving Transitivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of the matter is clearer as follows. Note $\ a\sim b\iff (a-b)/m\in\Bbb Z.$

i) $\ \ (a-a)/m \in \Bbb Z\ $ by $\ 0\in\Bbb Z$

ii) $\ \ (a-b)/m \in \Bbb Z \, \Rightarrow\, (b-a)/m \in \Bbb Z\ $ by $\ \Bbb Z\ $ closed under negation.

iii) $ \ (a-b)/m,\, (b-c)/m \in \Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, (a-c)/m \in \Bbb Z\ $  by $\ \Bbb Z\ $ closed under addition.

So congruence is an equivalence relation precisely because $\,\Bbb Z\,$ is an additive *subgroup* of $\,\Bbb Q.$