# Which theorem is used to reduce a linear congruence here?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$21x \equiv 49 \pmod{10}$?

21 % 10 = 1

and

49 % 10 = 9

So we can rewrite this as

$1x \equiv 9 \pmod{10}$

But which theorem shows that we can substitute the LHS & RHS with the remainder?

Comment: That's the definition of congruence. You can substitute an element by any element with the same remainder.

Comment: @AnuragA - where do I find this definition?

Comment: You used the Congruence Product Rule (see the dupe), and the the fact that [congruence is an equivalence relation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/655577/242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$, then $ax \equiv bx \pmod{n}$

Since $21 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$, we have $21x \equiv x \pmod{10}$.

Also, note that it is an equivalence relation, we have symmetric and transitivity.

Since $21x \equiv x \pmod{10}$ and $21x \equiv 49 \pmod{10}$,

We have  $$ x \equiv 49\pmod{10}$$

Again, since $x \equiv 49 \pmod{10}$ and $49 \equiv 9 \pmod{10}$, we have $$x \equiv 9 \pmod{10}.$$